# Machine learning - How to get the bias from svm?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am using libsvm with RBF kernel. After parameter selection, I am training my SVM. In the output after executing ./svm-train, which value represents the bias and what is the significance of bias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rho is the bias term in the decision function `sgn(w^Tx - rho)`

Comment: Thanks Eric..I was asked to vary the bias and observe the distribution of scores of the 2 classes(Its a bi-classification problem). What does this mean exactly?

Comment: See the binary classification problem as finding the best line (y=ax+b) with b=bias to separate two cluster of 2d-data points. SVM find the best function with largest margin... etc...